# Conservar datos

Tags: c#, sql-server, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Soy nuevo en cuanto asp.net MVC y tengo una gran duda, en mi botón editar, quisiera que al poner una de las opciones mencionadas en la imagen, no solo se edite el registro, sino conservar un duplicado del registro y la "edición" cree un nuevo registro con el estatus activo, y el duplicado quede sin poder seleccionar pero con el estatus modificado

```
[HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Editar(reserva a)
    {
        try
        {
            using (pruebareserva db = new pruebareserva ())
            {
                return RedirectToAction("TablaReserva");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Error al agregar la reserva", ex);
            throw;
        }
    }`

[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult editar()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

de igual formar quisiera que la cancelación quede el registro sin poder editar, y se actualice el estatus a cancelado.
No se si lo que estoy intentando hacer tiene coherencia, o si me estoy dando a entender de lo que quisiera hacer, pero si alguien me entiende seria de gran ayuda su respuesta.

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult cancelar(reserva a)
    {
        try
        {
            using (pruebareserva db = new pruebareserva ())
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("Error durante la cancelación", ex);
            throw;
        }
    }`

    `[HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult cancelar()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Actualmente tengo una tabla de reservas con los siguientes datos, en estado tendré activo, modificado, y cancelado

[image]

Comment: Pero cual seria el problema?

Comment: El código para poder hacer el duplicado del registro, no se si en otra tabla o en la misma, lo que quiero es conservar un historial de las cancelaciones y los cambios solicitados a las reservaciones, guardando x cantidad de duplicados por modificación, y en dado caso de una cancelación, inhabilitar el registro con el estado de cancelado "inabilitarlo en la vista de la tabla

Comment: Necesitas una tabla igual, que sea la historica, donde vayas guardando eso...

Comment: Pero, en ese caso el PK de reserva en la histórica no tendría que haber llaves primarias ni fk cierto? solo la duplicación de los datos al momento de cambiar el status a modificado o a cancelado? y como hago esa duplicación de datos de una tabla a otra dependiendo del estatus desde mi controlador?

Comment: Las tablas historicas en general guardan la informacion de forma historica. No guardan FK (guardan los datos puros, salvo que tus tablas hijas tengan periodos) y las PK se guardan tambien (si son parte del negocio o hay que referenciar al padre). pero tienen su propia PK. lo que no entiendo es cual es el problema que tenes al querer copiar datos de una tabla a otra...

Comment: A, que no se de que manera hacer referencias en asp a los campos de las tablas para poder duplicarlos en una nueva tabla, osea, que tengo que poner para que se haga la duplicación, como llamo los datos de una tabla y los mando a la otra con su nuevo estatus, pero en la actual conservando el activo, o eliminándolos del actual y mandándolos a la otra como cancelación, ese es mi problema, la codificación para hacerlo

Comment: que es `pruebareserva ` ? como estas insertando los registros en la tabla? porque en el codigo no veo ninguna operacion sobre datos

Answer (score 1):

Para generar un historico si tu db es `Sql Server` se usa `trigger` no necesitas hacer nada en tu codigo solo pones un disparador ante el evento de `insert` o `update` para que copie los registros de una tabla a la de historico.

Info hay mucha y este camino no ensucia tu codigo con una operacion que puede hacer perfectamente la db y es un tema de copia de datos y auditoria

[SQL Trigger : SQL Server Trigger Example to Log Changes History of a SQL Table](http://www.kodyaz.com/articles/sql-trigger-sql-server-trigger-example-to-log-changes-history.aspx)

Como observaras en el articulo crea dos tablas `CustomerCreditLimits` y `CustomerCreditLimitsHistory`, tu tienes que hacer lo mismo.

Despues crea un trigger

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.LogCustomerCreditLimitChanges
    ON dbo.CustomerCreditLimits
AFTER UPDATE, DELETE
AS
...
```

en este caso `AFTER` una actualizacion o borrado, tu podrias usar estos o solo la actualizacion

En los `trigger` tienes objetos para conocer el registro que se esta actualizando por eso usa el `Inserted` para generar el INSERT en la tabla de historico

Tambien puedes crear trigger indivisuales para cada accion separado asi es mas simple de entender y no poner IF para complicarlo

[SQL BLOG: Using Triggers for creating history tables in SQL Server](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/sql-blog-using-triggers-for-creating-history-tables-in-sql-server)

[Create a Simple SQL Server Trigger to Build an Audit Trail](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4055/create-a-simple-sql-server-trigger-to-build-an-audit-trail/)

en estos otro ejemplos la tabla en lugar de llamarla `history` la llaman `Audit` pero es le mismo concepto